# DateTime between dates pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How can I get weekly data in mysql ? 
This code does not work for me.

```
 public function getWeeklyWinners() {
            $today = time();
            $a_week_ago = strtotime("-1 week");
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM money_transfer WHERE send_date BETWEEN ? AND ?";
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute(array($today, $a_week_ago));
            if ($query->rowCount())
                return $query->fetchAll();
            return false;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: If it doesn't work for you  (whatever that means) it's because $today and $a_week_ago don't have the right values. You haven't shared that piece of info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `date_sub` or `INTERVAL`

```
SELECT * FROM money_transfer WHERE send_date 
BETWEEN date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now();
```

Comment: if my answer helps you please accept my answer :) @LeventTulun

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are generating a Unix time, and not a date, change the code that generates your FROM and TO dates so they generate the dates in the format `2015-12-01 00:00:00` `2015-11-24 00:00:00` and and your code should work.

If you were writing the query by hand you would expect to code it like this

```
SELECT * FROM money_transfer WHERE send_date BETWEEN '2015-11-24 00:00:00' AND '2015-11-24 00:00:00'
```

But your code will generate

```
SELECT * FROM money_transfer WHERE send_date BETWEEN '1448962584' AND '1448357784'
```

So a minor change to the date generation like this should work

```
public function getWeeklyWinners() {
    $today = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
    $a_week_ago = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00',strtotime("-1 week"));

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM money_transfer WHERE send_date BETWEEN ? AND ?";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array($a_week_ago, $today));
    if ($query->rowCount())
        return $query->fetchAll();
    return false;
}
```